# req.headers.authorization is undefined when I make a POST request to my API route in production (works in local dev server)

Tags: api, next.js, request, authorization, bearer-token

When I serve my application locally, I can access `req.headers.authorization` to read my Bearer Token. The same code is used in my deployed application, but when I make the same POST request to my live API route, `req.headers` is `undefined` in my NextJS API route. Why is this the case? Am I missing something about `req.headers` in NextJS that is unique to a deployed application?

Happy to provide more information as necessary! Thank you!

```js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  console.log('req ' + req);
  console.log('req.headers ' + req.headers);
  console.log('req.headers.authorization: ' + req.headers.authorization);

// ...etc.
```

When I run the dev server, I can read the Bearer Token successfully, and I can read it in the logs shown above, but in production the requests' `req.headers.authorization` is `undefined`.

I've tried accessing the Bearer Token in my request headers, but I can only do so in a development server environment. This fails when I make the very same request to my live, hosted application.

Comment: Can you show us how you're making the POST request from your app?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the post now. Thanks for your response, this is my first time posting a question here!

Comment: I'm using thunder client (VS code extension) for the requests. I've added a Bearer Token in the Auth tab. The POST request to my dev server, and the POST request to my production application are identical excepting the URL. One is to "http://localhost:3000/api/email_subscribers" and the other is to "http://punch-in.app/api/email_subscribers". The request to localhost yields a 200 response, while the live api route yields 500 "internal service error". I am certain that the bearer token is entered identically on both requests, but req.headers.authorization is undefined in the non-local request.

Comment: I would have shared a screenshot, but as a new contributor I don't yet have permission. I'm happy to provide more info -- but if I knew what info to provide I suppose I would have solved this myself by now! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to hit the endpoint and use my Bearer token by making a curl request and adding 'www' to the URL:

```
curl --request POST \
      --url 'https://www.example.com/api/my_route' \
      --header 'Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.EMAIL_ROUTE_SECRET }}'
```

I'm not sure what fixed it -- might be an issue with thunder client.

Comment: Thank you so much for coming back to answer this, been banging my head against the wall on this one!